# NameSpace resharper rules

Tags: coding-style, resharper

I am creating a dotsettings file for corporate use.  This file should conform to the coding standards for the company.

One of the standards states that Attributes and Exceptions should be Suffixed with Attribute and Exception.  Considering these will inherit from both System.Exception and System.Attribute, I was wondering if it is possible to write a rule that you can save into a dotSettings file to say as much?

Thanks in advance

Will